# Flink crashes after k8s master node restart

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to Flink. I am using Flink 1.12 in standalone mode and using k8s as HA.

When I was testing the resiliency by restarting the master node of k8s cluster, Flink jobmanager ,and taskmanagers crash.

Does anyone know why is it? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: He Jerome, can you share how does it crashes? Maybe some log output

Comment: Without extensive information on your cluster setup (amount of nodes, which are configured as master,workers), detailed information from `$ kubectl describe`, `$ kubectl logs` (from relevant components) it could be hard to point you why it failed. Please update your question with the points that I've described.